# Parse server migration to IBM bluemix

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, ibm-cloud, parse-server

I am trying to run parse server with nodejs in ibm bluemix but it is throwing an error in parse server PromiseRouter file.

```
PromiseRouter.js:48
        throw _iteratorError;
              ^
ReferenceError: Symbol is not defined
```

How can i get this resolved

My App .js

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

// Specify the connection string for your mongodb database 
// and the location to your Parse cloud code 
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://IBM_MONGO_DB',
  cloud: './cloud/main.js', // Provide an absolute path 
  appId: 'MYAPPID',
  masterKey: 'MYMASTER_KEY', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret! 
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:' + port + '/parse' // Don't forget to change to https if needed 
});
app.use('/parse', api);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('Express is running here.');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

Response :

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IBM_bluemix/Development/my_node_app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/PromiseRouter.js:48
        throw _iteratorError;
              ^
ReferenceError: Symbol is not defined
    at PromiseRouter.merge (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IBM_bluemix/Development/my_node_app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/PromiseRouter.js:33:40)
    at new ParseServer (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IBM_bluemix/Development/my_node_app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/index.js:137:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IBM_bluemix/Development/my_node_app/app.js:10:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

This is the function in PromiseRouter.js that is throwing an error

```
PromiseRouter.prototype.merge = function (router) {
  var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
  var _didIteratorError = false;
  var _iteratorError = undefined;

  try {
    for (var _iterator = router.routes[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
      var route = _step.value;

      this.routes.push(route);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    _didIteratorError = true;
    _iteratorError = err;
  } finally {
    try {
      if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return) {
        _iterator.return();
      }
    } finally {
      if (_didIteratorError) {
        throw _iteratorError;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

This is all i have

Comment: Is this the only output? Hard to tell what is happening with just these 2 lines. Thanks

Comment: Hello @BenRondeau I have added whatever i have and the whole response.

Comment: Answered. I believe that should solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `Symbol` is not found is because it is an [ES6 feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) that is not supported in your current Node.js build. Check to make sure your Node.js runtime is at least v4 ([see compatibility here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)).

The easy way to ensure your Node.js build on Bluemix is running at least v4.0 is to define your `engine` variable in your app's `package.json` file as such:

```
{ "engines" : { "node" : ">=4.0" } }
```

After updating your `package.json` file, re-push your application to Bluemix and it will build it with your defined version of Node.js

Comment: You are right. I was using bluemix default node which is 0.2.x