# Deploying parse-on-bluemix node.js app to bluemix failing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, ibm-cloud, compose-db

I am deploying node.js in Bluemix and basically migrating from parse.com to Bluemix.

What does the following error mean? How do I resolve it? I am using CF command line tool.
The log attached below.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
-----> Checking and configuring service extensions after installing dependencies
    -----> Installing App Management
    -----> Caching build
           Clearing previous node cache
           Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
           - node_modules
           - bower_components (nothing to cache)
    -----> Build succeeded!
           ├── cf-deployment-tracker-client@0.0.7
           ├── express@4.13.4
           └── parse-server@2.1.2

    -----> Uploading droplet (21M)

    0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
    0 of 1 instances running, 1 failing
    FAILED
    Start unsuccessful

    TIP: use 'cf logs sobmangoDB --recent' for more information



    2016-02-20T03:15:08.65-0500 [STG/0]      ERR 
    2016-02-20T03:15:14.31-0500 [STG/34]     OUT -----> Uploading droplet (21M)
    2016-02-20T03:15:21.82-0500 [DEA/34]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6
    2016-02-20T03:15:34.09-0500 [App/0]      OUT 
    2016-02-20T03:15:34.09-0500 [App/0]      OUT > parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start /home/vcap/app
    2016-02-20T03:15:34.09-0500 [App/0]      OUT > node index.js
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.44-0500 [App/0]      ERR 
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.44-0500 [App/0]      ERR /home/vcap/app/index.js:25
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.44-0500 [App/0]      ERR   throw 'Please apply the Application ID from Parse.com';
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.44-0500 [App/0]      ERR   ^
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.44-0500 [App/0]      ERR Please apply the Application ID from Parse.com
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! node v4.2.5
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start: `node index.js`
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Exit status 1
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! 
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Failed at the parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start script 'node index.js'.
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the parse-on-bluemix package,
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     node index.js
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-on-bluemix
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.54-0500 [DEA/34]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.60-0500 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6", "version"=>"5ea8150c-193e-4be1-83c6-aa7f6799e26f", "instance"=>"c5fcad4e778e4d009c4877d195bb5731", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1455956135}
    2016-02-20T03:15:35.63-0500 [API/10]     OUT App instance exited with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6", "version"=>"5ea8150c-193e-4be1-83c6-aa7f6799e26f", "instance"=>"c5fcad4e778e4d009c4877d195bb5731", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1455956135}
    2016-02-20T03:16:22.82-0500 [DEA/63]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6
    2016-02-20T03:16:35.01-0500 [App/0]      OUT 
    2016-02-20T03:16:35.01-0500 [App/0]      OUT > parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start /home/vcap/app
    2016-02-20T03:16:35.01-0500 [App/0]      OUT > node index.js
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.37-0500 [App/0]      ERR 
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.37-0500 [App/0]      ERR /home/vcap/app/index.js:25
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.37-0500 [App/0]      ERR   throw 'Please apply the Application ID from Parse.com';
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.37-0500 [App/0]      ERR   ^
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.37-0500 [App/0]      ERR Please apply the Application ID from Parse.com
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! node v4.2.5
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start: `node index.js`
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Exit status 1
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! 
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Failed at the parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start script 'node index.js'.
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the parse-on-bluemix package,
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     node index.js
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-on-bluemix
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.41-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.41-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.48-0500 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6", "version"=>"5ea8150c-193e-4be1-83c6-aa7f6799e26f", "instance"=>"186cd8bbf1284ba0846441e330db833b", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1455956196}
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.50-0500 [DEA/63]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
    2016-02-20T03:16:36.52-0500 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6", "version"=>"5ea8150c-193e-4be1-83c6-aa7f6799e26f", "instance"=>"186cd8bbf1284ba0846441e330db833b", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1455956196}
    2016-02-20T03:17:24.04-0500 [DEA/196]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6
    2016-02-20T03:17:36.99-0500 [App/0]      OUT 
    2016-02-20T03:17:36.99-0500 [App/0]      OUT > parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start /home/vcap/app
    2016-02-20T03:17:36.99-0500 [App/0]      OUT > node index.js
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR 
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR /home/vcap/app/index.js:25
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR   throw 'Please apply the Application ID from Parse.com';
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR   ^
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR Please apply the Application ID from Parse.com
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.45-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! node v4.2.5
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start: `node index.js`
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Exit status 1
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! 
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Failed at the parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start script 'node index.js'.
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the parse-on-bluemix package,
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     node index.js
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-on-bluemix
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.46-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.47-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.58-0500 [API/8]      OUT App instance exited with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6", "version"=>"5ea8150c-193e-4be1-83c6-aa7f6799e26f", "instance"=>"bd07162306f0482a8cf663b49926d989", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1455956258}
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.58-0500 [DEA/196]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
    2016-02-20T03:17:38.62-0500 [API/10]     OUT App instance exited with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6", "version"=>"5ea8150c-193e-4be1-83c6-aa7f6799e26f", "instance"=>"bd07162306f0482a8cf663b49926d989", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1455956258}
    2016-02-20T03:18:22.69-0500 [DEA/56]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6
    2016-02-20T03:18:37.56-0500 [App/0]      OUT 
    2016-02-20T03:18:37.56-0500 [App/0]      OUT > parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start /home/vcap/app
    2016-02-20T03:18:37.56-0500 [App/0]      OUT > node index.js
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR 
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR /home/vcap/app/index.js:25
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR   throw 'Please apply the Application ID from Parse.com';
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR   ^
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.40-0500 [App/0]      ERR Please apply the Application ID from Parse.com
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! node v4.2.5
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start: `node index.js`
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Exit status 1
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! 
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Failed at the parse-on-bluemix@0.0.1 start script 'node index.js'.
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the parse-on-bluemix package,
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Tell the author th

at this fails on your system:
        2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     node index.js
        2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! You can get their info via:
        2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-on-bluemix
        2016-02-20T03:18:39.42-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
        2016-02-20T03:18:39.43-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
        2016-02-20T03:18:39.43-0500 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
        2016-02-20T03:18:39.52-0500 [DEA/56]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-02-20T03:18:39.55-0500 [API/5]      OUT App instance exited with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6", "version"=>"5ea8150c-193e-4be1-83c6-aa7f6799e26f", "instance"=>"d88f3c035bc64e7ba3d1680859cc14d1", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1455956319}
2016-02-20T03:18:39.56-0500 [API/3]      OUT App instance exited with guid f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"f372acf6-f8de-4f97-94d1-661b945ac7b6", "version"=>"5ea8150c-193e-4be1-83c6-aa7f6799e26f", "instance"=>"d88f3c035bc64e7ba3d1680859cc14d1", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1455956319}
```

Comment: Please use `cf logs --recent` command to get full log output, then post here. It is also possible your problem might be solved with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466853/parse-server-migration-to-ibm-bluemix/35469011#35469011

Answer (score 1):

You have a NodeJS capability/Library parse-on-bluemix  that requires a license, API key or other credential from and external service provider Parse.com that isn't accessible or works with Bluemix.   Your options are:

1. Replace the service/capability with one that Bluemix or another service can provide.  so that you no longer have the dependency on parse-on-bluemix and Parse.com
2. OR create the necessary key/ token/ authorization from Parse.com and make it so that your code can access that key before it makes requests to that service or Capability on Parse.com.   There are a variety of ways you can do this:

   - Create user defined environment variables in Bluemix. [Set Bluemix VCAP_SERVICES environment variable locally so that I can develop locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007641/set-bluemix-vcap-services-environment-variable-locally-so-that-i-can-develop-loc)
   - Add a .env file that bluemix / your app will automatically read in to get the get before you call your Parse.com services.

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly says,

```
 ERR   throw 'Please apply the Application ID from Parse.com';
```

I did not update environment variables to APP_KEY of my parse app.

Thanks