# Set Bluemix VCAP_SERVICES environment variable locally so that I can develop locally?

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am trying to set my Bluemix [`VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#VCAP-SERVICES) locally, but I'm getting this error in the terminal:

> NoSQL: command not found

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Login to Bluemix.net
2. Deploy a [hello world flask application](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/python-hello-world-flask)
3. Bind a Bluemix Cloudant Service to the application
4. Copy the `VCAP_SERVICES` Environment Variables from the Runtime / Environment Variables on the application for Python
5. In local editor remove all the line breaks on Mac terminal
6. `vi ~/.bash_profile`
7. Enter insert mode with `i`
8. paste in `VCAPSERVICES`, mine looks like this:

   ```
   VCAP_SERVICES="{"VCAP_SERVICES":{"cloudantNoSQLDB": [{"credentials": {"host": "fakehostc-bluemix.cloudant.com","password":"fakepassword4da6de3a12a83362b26a","port": 443,"url": "https://fakeURLc-bluemix:fakeab96175c-bluemix.cloudant.com","username": "fakeusername-b749-399cfbd1175c-bluemix"},"label":"cloudantNoSQLDB","name":"Cloudant NoSQL DB-p2","plan":"Lite","provider":null,"syslog_drain_url":null,"tags":["data_management","ibm_created","ibm_dedicated_public"]}]}}"
   export VCAP_SERVICES
   ```
9. Save the file and quit `vi` with `:wq!`
10. Source the modified file with `. ~/.bash_profile` to set the terminal window with the new VCAP Environment Variable

What am I doing wrong copying and setting my local Bluemix VCAP_Services Environment Variable?

If I copy the whole thing I get errors that the line is too long.   How can I easily copy and paste the entire Bluemix Python Runtime `VCAP_SERVICES` Variable into my local Mac `.bash_profile` environment settings without manually massaging JSON and all these line breaks etc?

I don't want to use a local file to store those since it isn't very secure as I move from dev, test, staging and production.

Comment: I improved the formatting of your question to make it easier to read. Please review Stack Overflow's formatting documentation in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can do this yourself next time. Note that code blocks inside a list need to be indented four spaces for each list level, plus an additional four spaces to indicate a code block. I also moved part of you problem statement before your steps to reproduce for better context. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Chris for the edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer use single quotes at the beginning and end of VCAP_SERVICES

> VCAP_SERVICES='{"cloudantNoSQLDB": [{"credentials": {"host": "fakehostc-bluemix.cloudant.com","password":"fakepassword4da6de3a12a83362b26a","port": 443,"url": "https://fakeURLc-bluemix:fakeab96175c-bluemix.cloudant.com","username": "fakeusername-b749-399cfbd1175c-bluemix"},"label":"cloudantNoSQLDB","name":"Cloudant NoSQL DB-p2","plan":"Lite","provider":null,"syslog_drain_url":null,"tags":["data_management","ibm_created","ibm_dedicated_public"]}]}'

Here is the corresponding code to retrieve VCAP Services environment variables and do basic operations on Cloudant:

```
# 1. Parse VCAP_SERVICES Variable and connect to DB         
vcap = json.loads(os.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"))['cloudantNoSQLDB']        
serviceUsername = vcap[0]['credentials']['username']
servicePassword = vcap[0]['credentials']['password']    
serviceURL = vcap[0]['credentials']['url']

# Create Cloudant DB connection
# This is the name of the database we are working with.
databaseName = "databasedemo"

# This is a simple collection of data,
# to store within the database.
sampleData = [
    [1, "one", "boiling", 100],
    [2, "two", "hot", 40],
    [3, "three", "warm", 20],
    [4, "four", "cold", 10],
    [5, "five", "freezing", 0]
]

# Use the Cloudant library to create a Cloudant client.
client = Cloudant(serviceUsername, servicePassword, url=serviceURL)

# Connect to the server
client.connect()

# 2.  Creating a database within the service instance.

# Create an instance of the database.
myDatabaseDemo = client.create_database(databaseName)

# Check that the database now exists.
if myDatabaseDemo.exists():
    print "'{0}' successfully created.\n".format(databaseName)

# 3.  Storing a small collection of data as documents within the database.

# Create documents using the sample data.
# Go through each row in the array
for document in sampleData:
    # Retrieve the fields in each row.
    number = document[0]
    name = document[1]
    description = document[2]
    temperature = document[3]

    # Create a JSON document that represents
    # all the data in the row.
    jsonDocument = {
        "numberField": number,
        "nameField": name,
        "descriptionField": description,
        "temperatureField": temperature
    }

    # Create a document using the Database API.
    newDocument = myDatabaseDemo.create_document(jsonDocument)

    # Check that the document exists in the database.
    if newDocument.exists():
        print "Document '{0}' successfully created.".format(number)

# 4.  Retrieving a complete list of the documents.

# Simple and minimal retrieval of the first
# document in the database.
result_collection = Result(myDatabaseDemo.all_docs)
print "Retrieved minimal document:\n{0}\n".format(result_collection[0])

# Simple and full retrieval of the first
# document in the database.
result_collection = Result(myDatabaseDemo.all_docs, include_docs=True)
print "Retrieved full document:\n{0}\n".format(result_collection[0])

# Use a Cloudant API endpoint to retrieve
# all the documents in the database,
# including their content.

# Define the end point and parameters
end_point = '{0}/{1}'.format(serviceURL, databaseName + "/_all_docs")
params = {'include_docs': 'true'}

# Issue the request
response = client.r_session.get(end_point, params=params)

# Display the response content
print "{0}\n".format(response.json())

# 5.  Deleting the database.

# Delete the test database.
try :
    client.delete_database(databaseName)
except CloudantException:
    print "There was a problem deleting '{0}'.\n".format(databaseName)
else:
    print "'{0}' successfully deleted.\n".format(databaseName)

# 6.  Closing the connection to the service instance.

# Disconnect from the server
client.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an anti-pattern to create the VCAP_SERVICES env variable locally. I suggest just using the connecting info when running locally.

Option 1

```
if 'VCAP_SERVICES' in os.environ:
    services = json.loads(os.getenv('VCAP_SERVICES'))
    cloudant_url = services['cloudantNoSQLDB'][0]['credentials']['url']
else:
    cloudant_url = "https://fakeURLc-bluemix:fakeab96175c-bluemix.cloudant.com"
```

Option 2

If you don't want to hardcode credentials into your code, then you can create a `.env` file:

```
export LOCAL_CLOUDANT_URL=https://fakeURLc-bluemix:fakeab96175c-bluemix.cloudant.com
```

and in your python code:

```
if 'VCAP_SERVICES' in os.environ:
    services = json.loads(os.getenv('VCAP_SERVICES'))
    cloudant_url = services['cloudantNoSQLDB'][0]['credentials']['url']
else:
    cloudant_url = os.environ['LOCAL_CLOUDANT_URL']
```

and then `source .env` before you run your application.

Be sure to add `.env` to `.gitignore` and `.cfignore`

Comment: Hi Ram,  I already have the python code to read the VCAP_Services Environment variable. My problem is setting it  vi ~/.bash_profile after copying it from the Bluemix Python Runtime environment copy icon in the dashboard or doing a cf env myapp .  I figured out I needed to add single quote at beginning and end of it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a cf CLI plugin that will get VCAP_SERVICES from your app and help you set it locally. I've used it on my Mac and didn't have to adjust the quotes at all.

Checkout https://github.com/jthomas/copyenv